# AngularJS uiRouter access controller from other view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have simple hierarchical state:

```
angular
    .module('App.Module.Suppliers', [])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        return $stateProvider
            .state('suppliers', {
                url: '/suppliers',
                views: {
                    main: {
                        templateUrl: 'views/layouts/wrapper.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('suppliers.edit', {
                url: '/:id',
                views: {
                    entity_view: {
                        templateUrl: 'views/layouts/foo.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('suppliers.edit.details', {
                url: '/edit',
                views: {
                    entity_sub_view: {
                        controller: function () {
                            this.foo = {bar: "TEST HEADER"};
                        },
                        controllerAs: 'vm',
                        templateUrl: 'views/layouts/main.html'
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

`main` and `entity_view` views are generic for all entities and only `entity_sub_view` changes with core information.

---

Now in `entity_view` I want to use some value like `<h2>{{vm.foo.bar}}</h2>` but it seems that I can't access `vm` inside these parent states.

Is there a way to pass this and other parameters to parent states to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found solution that fits my need. Basically you can set `controllerAs` to top-most state and access it via `$scope`:

```js
angular
    .module('App.Module.Suppliers', [])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        return $stateProvider
            .state('suppliers', {
                url: '/suppliers',
                views: {
                    main: {
                        templateUrl: 'views/layouts/wrapper.html'
                        controller: function () {
                            this.foo = null;
                        }
                        controllerAs: 'mainCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('suppliers.edit', {
                url: '/:id',
                views: {
                    entity_view: {
                        templateUrl: 'views/layouts/foo.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('suppliers.edit.details', {
                url: '/edit',
                views: {
                    entity_sub_view: {
                        controller: function () {
                            this.foo = {bar: "TEST HEADER"};
                        },
                        controllerAs: 'vm',
                        templateUrl: 'views/layouts/main.html'
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

And in some controller do

```js
this.$scope.mainCtrl.foo = {bar: "TEST HEADER"};
```

In view

```js
{{mainCtrl.foo.bar}}
```